# Is it possible to tell when a user update the app?

Tags: ios, app-store

A user installed my app, and I released a new version.
If the app is in background, and the user is updating the app, is it possible for the existing version to get a notification about it?

(The reason I'm asking is that I have a VPN app, and if the user activated the VPN and try to update the app while the VPN is open - the update won't succeed, so I need to close it first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app gets terminated before the update starts and I guess there is no notification sent to the app before that happens.

Comment: Thanks. That what I thought, but I don't understand why the VPN connection is still active. If the app got terminated, it should clear it's VPN configuration as well..

Comment: You may want to try using the `applicationWillTerminate:` method in your AppDelegate and tell it to close the VPN connection. However, I am not sure you can guarantee this is always called.